# What happens if you remove the space between the + and ++ operators?

Tags: java, integer, operators, string-concatenation, addition

**EDIT 1**

DISCLAIMER: *I know that* `+++` *is not really an operator* but the `+` and `++` operators without a space. I also know that there's no reason to use this; this question is just out of curiosity.

---

So, I'm interested to see if the space between `+` and `++var` is required in Java.

Here is my test code:

```
int i = 0;
System.out.println(i);
i = i +++i;
System.out.println(i);
```

This prints out:

```
0
1
```

which works as I would expect, just as if there were a space between the first and second `+`.

Then, I tried it with string concatenation:

```
String s1 = "s " + ++i;
System.out.println(s1);
// String s2 = "s " +++i;
```

This prints out:

```
s 2
```

But if the third line is uncommented, the code does not compile, with the error:

```
Problem3.java:13: unexpected type
required: variable
found   : value
    String s2 = "s " +++i;
                ^
Problem3.java:13: operator + cannot be applied to <any>,int
    String s2 = "s " +++i;
                     ^
```

What's causing the difference in behavior between string concatenation and integer addition?

---

**EDIT 2**

As discussed in [Abhijit's follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382171/is-its-just-a-post-fix-increment-followed-by-an-infix-always), the rule that people have mentioned (the larger token ++ be parsed first, before the shorter token ++) is discussed in [this presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1h49gY3TSiayLMXYmRMaAEMl05FaJ-Z6jDOWOz3EsqqQ/preview?sle=true#slide=id.gcfd0be4a_219) where it appears to be called the Munchy Munchy rule.

Comment: And simmilary i = i+++++i; is NOT valid but i = i++ + ++i; IS.

Comment: As it isn't an operator, asking how it works doesn't make sense. Not a real question.

Comment: Followup question [Is `+++` its just a post-fix increment followed by an infix (always)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15382171/977038)

Comment: @EJP But I had a disclaimer and everything! Have edited the title to make real question more obvious; I was just wondering about how + and ++ are parsed when there is no space between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler generates longest possible tokens when parsing source, so when it encounters **+++**, it takes it as **++ +**.

So the code of

```
a +++ b
```

Will always be same as

```
(a++) + b
```

Answer (score 13):

There is no `+++` operator.  What you have there is a postfix `++` operator followed by an infix `+` operator.  That is a compilation error because postfix `++` can only be applied to a variable, and `"s "` isn't a variable.

Since you really mean an infix `+` operator followed by a prefix `++` operator, you need to put the space in between the operators.

Actually, you should do it ANYWAY.  `+++` is a crime against readability!!!

Answer (score 2):

The triple plus is not an operator itself, it is two operators combined:

What the triple plus acutually does is:

a+++1 == a++ + 1;

What you are trying to do is ++ a String, which is undefined.

Never ever use +++ without spaces in your code; hardly anyone will know what it does (without consulting web). Moreover, after a week or so, you will not know what it actually does yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`+++` isn't an operator by itself.

`i = i +++i;` results in a *pre-increment* value of `i`, then adding it to the value of `i` and storing it in `i`.

With the String, `+` doesn't mean addition, so you're attempting to concatenate the string and the integer together.