# Is `+++` its just a post-fix increment followed by an infix (always)?

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++, g++

Consider the SO Question posted for Java [How does the +++ operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378392/how-does-the-operator-work)

Well I understand that

1. There is no operator like '+++' its just a post-fix increment followed by an infix add
2. Its a crime against readability

What I want to know (Just for the sake of curiosity) IF

`+++` its just a post-fix increment followed by an infix add **and not** `+++` its just an infix add followed by a prefix increment **or its an undefined behavior**.

Consider I have tested the following Program

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int x = 1;
    std::cout<< x+++1 << std::endl;
    std::cout<< 1+++x << std::endl;
}
```

in VC++, gcc and g++ and all of them conforms to the fact that

```
'+++' its just a post-fix increment followed by an infix add
```

and not

```
'+++' its just an infix add followed by a prefix increment
```

Comment: One *really* easy way to avoid problems is to write `++ +` or `+ ++` to indicate what you actually want. Even if the compiler knows the corner cases, your fellow programmers might not. Why confuse the heck out of them?

Comment: Reason for Down vote? May be because I was curious and even though I was not a cat it killed me?

Comment: I thought the -1 was obvious. The question is not useful, because there is no pratical use for the answer. Just like there is no use for [all of these questions about ++x + x++ etc](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f949433%2f*%22&lq=1).

Comment: +1 to compensate for the downvote. Questions that come out of curiosity may not be directly useful, but they help people understand the underlying processes in the language/compiler, which can often have at least as many good effects overall than a practical 'how do I do this'-type question. Also, Abhijit explicitly mentioned in the question that use of +++ is bad style; people reading *aren't* going to try to use it, so there are no *negative* effects, so no need for a downvote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if you remove the space between the + and ++ operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378392/what-happens-if-you-remove-the-space-between-the-and-operators)

Comment: This is functionally the same question, and if the original answers were unclear or left room for doubt, they should be clarified instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the **maximal munch rule** tells us that `+++` is parsed as `++ +` (not postfix followed by infix, but postfix followed by a `+` operator), which also renders

```
1+++x  <----> 1++ + x
```

illegal, because `1` isn't an lvalue.

Comment: great clarification about `lvalue`

Comment: Nice, so does the C++ Standard dictates the fact that the compilers should use **maximal munch rule**

Comment: There's a presentation about C talking about it, [Munchy munchy](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1h49gY3TSiayLMXYmRMaAEMl05FaJ-Z6jDOWOz3EsqqQ/edit#slide=id.gcfd0be4a_219) and [Munchy munchy.  Again.](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1h49gY3TSiayLMXYmRMaAEMl05FaJ-Z6jDOWOz3EsqqQ/edit#slide=id.gcfd0be4a_225), it talks about C but i think is the same in C++ and Java.

Comment: @Abhijit Yes, it does, in [lex.pptoken]§3. "... Otherwise, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token, even if that would cause further lexical analysis to fail."

Comment: @Angew didn't know that, I thought it was inferred from the grammar. Learn something new every day.